# How to stop critters from living in my garage soffits? Spray foam?

Tags: garage, soffit, rodent

We have had mice and snakes getting into the soffits of our garage. Over the past 3 years, I have worked to seal off any holes I could find, but a few months later and more critters would show up.
At this point, I'm considering just filling in the soffits so that there are no more issues, but I don't know if that will cause any problems. The garage has a ridge vent, so I don't think I'm creating any ventilation issues, but I want to ask the experts.

Comment: Mice will chew though foam.  Need metal to stop them.  Unlikely that snakes would choose soffits to enter, might need to look at other places.  Holes do not need to be that big, have heard that mice can go though 1/4 inch.

Comment: snakes feed on mice

Comment: Your ridge vent is only the exhaust half of your roof venting system - the other half are the intakes, normally the soffit vents. You don't want to block those. I'd look into what the mice find attractive and try to remove that if possible. Repellents may work, as mice have good smell - predator urine perhaps?

Comment: To address a few of the questions/comments, there are no soffit vents, I believe the mice are coming in for shelter, and the garage is cinder block, so I don't know of any other entry points where they could then get up to the soffits

Comment: Like mentioned by crip659, the rule is - at least here in Europe: mice can enter in any hole where a pencil can enter. The fur is very misleading. What could also help is a sound/sinus/high frequency generator specially made against rodents.